# Selecting Accordion H3 tag per chosen Category on Page Load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

**Background:** The user selects the Category from Home page and then the sub page is loaded showing the accordion for that ID passed. This accordion is entirely built from database values on page load. The accordion `<h3>` tag has the Category Name and the under that there are sub categories as `<ul>`.

I have removed the database extraction code that forms the accordion and purely pasting the HTML.

**Issue:** I am trying to Auto Expand the chosen Category accordion tag and below is my code. For example:, if value selected is **Switch** which is the 3rd `<h3>` tag, then on page load, this should be auto expanded instead of the 1st `<h3>` tag. I tried many other ways but seems not able to find the solution.

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#accordion").show().accordion(
    {
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: 0,
        icons:
        {
            header: 'ui-icon-circle-plus',
            headerSelected: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-n'
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="accordion">

    <h3 class="">Pressure Gauge</h3>

        <div>
            <ul class="ulStyle">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pressure Gauge</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Diff. Pressure Gauge</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Diaphragm Seal</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Snubber</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Gauge Cock</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <h3 class="">Temperature Gauge</h3>
        <div>
            <ul class="ulStyle">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Temperature Gauge</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Thermowell</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <h3 class="">Switch</h3>
        <div>
            <ul class="ulStyle">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pressure Switch</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Temperature Switch</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <h3 class="">Valves</h3>
        <div>
            <ul class="ulStyle">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Needle Valve</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Manifold</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Single Block & Bleed</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Double Block & Bleed</a>
                </li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>  

    <h3 class="">Flow Meter</h3>
        <div>
            <ul class="ulStyle">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Orifice Plate</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pilot Tube</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Venturi Tube</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Aerofoil</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Flow Nozzle</a>
                </li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>

</div>
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the parameter in the

```
active : Tab number to be activated on page load
```

So for this Pass the Category ID from home page to the sub page which will show that
category opened by default.
If you are using php then pass the category ID and get that on the sub page and use it lik this :

For example the url contains the parameter

```
subpage.php?tabdID=2 // This will be the switch category ID in your case.
```

After that get the tabID parameter in your subpage

```
$tabactive = $_GET['tabID'] OR $tabactive = $_REQUEST['tabID'];
$tabactive = (!empty($tabID)) ? $tabID : 1; // If empty them assign default to 1
```

Then in your javascript

```
$("#accordion").show().accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: <?php echo $tabactive; ?>, // Feed the value here and it shall work
    icons:
    {
        header: 'ui-icon-circle-plus',
        headerSelected: 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-n'
    }
});
```

Hope that helps. Remember you need to pass the tab ID from home page to sub page. And the jquery UI accordion ID starts from 0, 1, 2 ...

0 Means first accordion tab,

1 means second,

2 means third and so on........

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks, will try this and let you know the outcome. Appreciate

Comment: I tried it but it is not working accurately. My categories on home page are dynamic which means that the IDs are also dynamic. I have added the ids in the tag `<h3 id="3" data-id="3">`. System opens up the tab but some other tab not the chosen one since accordion tab index start from 0. I tried doing by subtracting 1 from the passed id but still not accurate. Also to add that the Categories are shown in the user defined Sort Sequence where Sort Sequence for ID 1 could be 10

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. After my last comment, I added the Sort Sequence number in the parameter and then fetched into a variable. The h3 tag ids were replaced with the Sort Sequence after deducting 1 to match the index. Thanks your idea helped.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you. Also you tried your best to solve the issue, that is great.